# Capitalize values of destructed object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

i have destructered `req.body` into:

```
const {
      logo = randomImg,
      category,
      name,
      owner,
      phone = "NA",
      location = "NA",
      website = "NA",
    } = req.body;
```

Now I want to capitalize name, owner.firstName, owner.lastname, and category.
How can I do that?

i tried:

```
[category,name].forEach((s)=>{
  if (typeof s !== 'string') return ''
  return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
})
```

but this doesn't seem to change the actual value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `typeof s` ? propably it should be word...

Comment: Consdier using map instead of forEach.

Comment: @sonic true dat.

Comment: I feel your pain. I can't tell you how often I've wanted to be able to run a destructured value through some kind of transformation function.

Comment: It doesnt work because `return` in `forEach` will exit the funcion and skip to the next element, it won't modify initial array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The good news is, it is possible https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/qtx839Lu/ . But, you will also get things thrown at you.

Comment: @adiga - LOL! Yes, yes you will... :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the wanted values and capitalize the strings and destruture the result to the given targets.

```
[name, owner.firstName, owner.lastname] = [name, owner.firstName, owner.lastname]
    .map(s => typeof s === 'string'
        ? s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
        : s
    );
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Yes, `name` and `category` are `const` but that's easily fixed.

Answer (score 3):

First off, a couple of notes:

- You can't change the value of a `const`. That's kind of what they're for. :-)
- Nothing pays any attention to the return value of `forEach`.
- Even if it did, nothing is going to know how those return values match up with your constants.

You have a couple of choices:

1. Use variables (`let`), and repeat the code for each variable (or use a loop like [Nina's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63120280/157247)); or
2. Don't use destructuring (at least initially)

Repeating isn't all *that* bad (if you use a reusable `toTitleCase` function or similar — which you want to do anyway, perhaps even a `toTitleCaseOrBlank` to handle the `typeof` check); you're only updating four things.

But assuming you don't want to, you could make a shallow copy of `req.body` and its `owner` object, update that shallow copy, and *then* destructure from that copy:

```
const copy = {...req.body, owner: {...req.body.owner}});
["name", "category"].forEach(name => copy[name] = toTitleCaseOrBlank(copy[name]));
["firstName", "lastName"].forEach(name => copy.owner[name] = toTitleCaseOrBlank(copy.owner[name]));
const {
    logo = randomImg,
    category,
    name,
    owner,
    phone = "NA",
    location = "NA",
    website = "NA",
} = copy;
```

That seems like a lot of work for four updates, though. :-)

Comment: thanks, seems like @Nina's answer is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld - Yeah, it's cute. For me it's overkill vs. just writing four lines of code for four items, but it's a judgement call. Note: If you're using her code exactly as is, you're directly modifying `req.body`, which I assumed above wasn't something you wanted to do. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So, the simplest way I can think of to solve this is to not destructure out those variables you're then going to change. Instead create the new variables directly. Something like the following:

```js
const toTitleCase = input -> typeof s === 'string'
        ? s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
        : s

const name = toTitleCase(req.body.name);
const category = toTitleCase(req.body.category);

const {
      logo = randomImg,
      owner,
      phone = "NA",
      location = "NA",
      website = "NA",
    } = req.body;

owner.firstName = toTitleCase(owner.firstName)
owner.lastName = toTitleCase(owner.lastName)
```

This approach avoids the complication of loops, though if the list of things you want to title-case is very long or subject to dynamic changes, you might want to use one of the looped approaches.